# HTML5 Video Loop - Memory Leak

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Looping a video continuously is creating a memory leak and causing the browser to crash

```
<video autoplay loop width="1920" height="1080" src="video/myVideo_v01.mp4"></video>
```

Has anyone had a similar experience with this? What solutions have you found?

Comment: No can't say that I have, Chrome, Firefox, or Safari? PC or Mac? Do you have anything else on your page? Does this happen if you place this in a blank page? Does this happen in a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/) or [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The video is playing on a blank page in IE 11, using a PC. For this application, the browser is restricted to IE

Comment: Ah, there's your answer, IE11. Add IE 11 as a tag, and to your title.Good luck.

Comment: do you have a test page with the video you're using? I've had IE11 running now for about 4 hours looping the same video with no issues... How long does it take for you to experience the problem?